# Хочу написать текстового помощника на Telegram или VK. С чего начать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, vkontakte-api

Хочу написать текстового помощника в **Telegram** или **VK** на языке Python.
Опыт программирования текстового помощника в самом Python уже есть. А вот с библиотекой `pyTelegramBotAPI` работал мало, с `VkAPI` вообще не работал.
Уже установил их через pip - `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` и `pip install VkAPI`. Всё вроде нормально установилось.
Подскажите, пожалуйста:

1. На чём лучше делать - **Telegram** или **VK**?
2. С чего начинать?

**P. S.** *Функции помощника я могу написать сам.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### На чём лучше делать - Telegram или VK?

На этот вопрос лучше ответить вам самим. Зависит от того, где бы вы больше всего хотели сделать своего бота, а также от возможности обоих платформ.

### С чего начинать?

Если начинать чего-то с простого, то могу рассказать о библиотеке [vkbottle](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/). Довольно простой, полностью типизированный, имеет много готовых вещей, асинхронный. В несколько строк можно добавить новый функционал в бота.

Так будет выглядеть простой бот, отвечающий на "Привет":

```py
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message

bot = Bot(token="token")

@bot.on.message(text="Привет")
async def hi_handler(message: Message):
    users_info = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
    await message.answer("Привет, {}".format(users_info[0].first_name))

bot.run_forever()
```

Comment: Раньше пользовался `pyTelegramBotAPI`, но большую часть я и мои знакомые проводят ВКонтакте, поэтому ботов в Телеграмме делать перестал. По нему тоже выходили новые библиотеки, похожие на `vkbottle`, но ничего подробного рассказать не смогу, сам не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо, буду писать на `VKbottle`!

Comment: А вместо `"token"` писать что?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8, суда вписывается токен сообщества, в котором будет работать бот (подробнее об `access_token` можно почитать здесь: https://vk.com/dev/access_token).
Его можно получить: Сообщество -> Управление -> Работа с API.
Так же нужно включить там LongPool и настроить события (в нашем случае, входящие сообщения).

Comment: ок, хорошо, буду знать